# How do I make content scroll in separate columns within a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a layout where the bottom portion of the page is a fixed-size, and the upper portion has columns that scroll independently. However I put my `height:100%; overflow-y: scroll` declarations on elements and their parents, I can't seem to get the columns to scroll, they always disappear underneath the bottom div, and indeed off the page without the scrollbars activating:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#main{
  flex:0.9;
  padding-top:2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#bottom{
  background: #1f132d;
  height: 10rem;
  flex:0.1;
}
.scroll-col{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <div class="container" id="main">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 scroll-col">
          <div style="background:#f00; height:500px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 scroll-col">
          <div style="background:#0f0; height:500px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 scroll-col">
          <div style="background:#00f; height:500px"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset overflow , flex-direction and flex a couple of time.

`flex:0.9` and `flex:0.1;` should be written `flex:9;` and `flex:1;`, for 2 children , ratios is the same 90% and 10% . But if you set `10rem` on `#bottom`, then `flex:1;` on `#main` is plenty enough to tell to fill space left.

```css
html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#bottom {
  background: #1f132d;
  height: 3rem;/* for snippet demo*/
}
.container,
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*height: 100%;  used h-100 class instead*/
}
.scroll-col {
  overflow: auto;
  /*height: 100%;  used h-100 class instead*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100" id="main">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-4 scroll-col h-100">
          <div style="background:#f00; height:500px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 scroll-col h-100">
          <div style="background:#0f0; height:1500px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 scroll-col h-100">
          <div style="background:#00f; height:250px"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VMNVNP